# Targeting generated pagination specifically

Tags: pagination, css-selectors

I need to target only specific li in an ul but I can't add a Class to solve my issue. I guess there's a way using Javascript, but it would be my last resort.
To explain:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Start</li>
        <li>Previous</li>
        <li>>1</li> <!--need to target this-->
        <li>2</li> <!--need to target this-->
        <li>3</li> <!--need to target this-->
        <li--in future a new li will be generated--/li>
        <li>Next</li>
        <li>End</li>
    </ul>
```

This example is only the general idea as my jsFiddle contains more info such as span and classes.
http://jsfiddle.net/8aW77/

note: I looked for [special](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) and [advanced](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) selectors but I couldn't find one that fits my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably you'd assign classes to the elements you **do** have control over, such as Start, Previous, Next and End. When you've done that, it's easy to style the other elements.

```
<ul>
    <li class="static">Start</li>
    <li class="static">Previous</li>
    <li>>1</li> <!--need to target this-->
    <li>2</li> <!--need to target this-->
    <li>3</li> <!--need to target this-->
    <li--in future a new li will be generated--/li>
    <li class="static">Next</li>
    <li class="static">End</li>
</ul>
```

Thus the CSS would look like:

```
UL LI {
    color: green;
}
UL LI.static {
    color: red;
}
```

This would be the most straight-forward solution. However, if you can't add those classes to the "static" LI-tags but you know that the DOM-structure will look the same then use CSS such as this:

```
UL LI {
    color: green;
}
UL LI:first-child,
UL LI:nth-child(2),
UL LI:nth-last-child(2),
UL LI:last-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: had found it already, it was stupid question but you answered it first so you deserve it.